# Array Types In Powershell - System.Object[] vs. arrays with specific types

Tags: arrays, powershell, collections, types, coercion

Why does caling `GetType().Name` on an array of strings return `Object[]` and not `String[]`? 
This seems to happen with any element type, for example `Import-Csv` will give you an `Object[]` but each element is a `PSCustomObject`.

Here's an example with an array of `String`

```
$x = @('a','b','c')

$x[0].GetType().Name #String
$x.GetType().Name #Object[]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you have not specified the data type of the array explicitly.

For instance, assigning an integer to `$x[1]` would work, because the array's type is `Object[]`.

If you specify a data type while constructing the array, you won't be able to assign values of an incompatible type later:

```
C:\PS> [int[]] $myArray = 12,64,8,64,12

C:\PS> $myArray.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                   
True     True     Int32[]                                  System.Array               



C:\PS> $myArray[0] = "asd"
Cannot convert value "asd" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a c
orrect format."
At line:1 char:1
+ $myArray[0] = "asd"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

Answer (score 34):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for all his help.</sup>

To complement [Miroslav Adamec's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355869/45375) with ***why* PowerShell creates `System.Object[]` arrays by default** and additional background information:

PowerShell's default arrays are meant to be **flexible**:

- they allow you to **store objects of *any type*** (including `$null`),
- even allowing you to ***mix* objects of different types in a single array**.

**To enable this, the array must be (implicitly) typed as `[object[]]` (`[System.Object[]]`)**, because `System.Object` is the single root of the entire .NET type hierarchy from which all other types derive.

For instance, the following creates an `[object[]]` array whose elements are of type `[string]`, `[int]`, `[datetime]`, and `$null`, respectively.

```bash
# Note:
#  * @(...) is not strictly needed
#  * Use , <val> to create a 1-element array
$arr = 'hi', 42, (Get-Date), $null
```

When you:

- create an array by using the **array *construction* operator**, **`,`**
- force command output into an array by using the **array *subexpression* operator**, **`@(...)`**
- **save to a variable** the **output from a command** that emits **a *collection* of objects with *2 or more* elements, *irrespective of the specific type of the original collection***, or operate on it in the context of another command by **enclosing it in `(...)`**

you ***always* get a `System.Object[]` array** - even if all the elements *happen to* have the same type, as in your example.

---

#### Optional Further Reading

PowerShell's **default arrays are convenient, but have drawbacks**:

- They provide **no type safety**: if you want to ensure that all elements are of a specific type (or should be converted to it, if possible), a default array won't do; e.g.:

  ```bash
    $intArray = 1, 2      # An array of [int] values.
    $intArray[0] = 'one'  # !! Works, because a [System.Object[]] array can hold any type.
  ```
- `[System.Object[]]` arrays are **inefficient for *value types*** such as `[int]`, because [*boxing* and *unboxing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) must be performed - though that may often not matter in the real world.

Since PowerShell provides access to the .NET type system, you can avoid the drawbacks if you **create an array that is restricted to the specific type of interest, using a *cast* or *type-constrained variable***:

```bash
[int[]] $intArray = 1, 2  # A type-constrained array of [int] variable.
$intArray[0] = 'one'      # BREAKS: 'one' can't be converted to an [int]
```

Note that using a *cast* to create the array - `$intArray = [int[]] (1, 2)` - would have worked too, but only the type-constrained variable ensures that you cannot *later* assign a value of a different type to the *variable* (e.g., `$intArray = 'one', 'two'` would fail).

<sup>**Syntax pitfall with *casts***: `[int[]] 1, 2` does *not* work as intended, because casts have high [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx), so the expression is evaluated as `([int[]] 1), 2`, which creates a regular `[object[]]` array whose *first* element is a *nested* `[int[]]` array with single element `1`.

**When in doubt, use `@(...)` around your array elements**<sup>[1]</sup>, which is also required if you want to ensure that an expression that may return only a *single* item is always treated as an array.</sup>

---

#### Pitfalls

**PowerShell performs many type conversions behind the scenes**, which are typically very helpful, but there are **pitfalls**:

- PowerShell **automatically tries to coerce a value to a target type**, which you don't always want and may not notice:

  ```bash
    [string[]] $a = 'one', 'two'
    $a[0] = 1    # [int] 1 is quietly coerced to [string]

    # The coercion happens even if you use a cast:
    [string[]] $a = 'one', 'two'
    $a[0] = [int] 1    # Quiet coercion to [string] still happens.
  ```

  Note: That even an explicit cast - `[int] 1` - causes quiet coercion may or may not be a surprise to you. My surprise came from - incorrectly - assuming that in an auto-coercing language such as PowerShell casts might be a way to *bypass* the coercion - which is *not* true.<sup>[2]</sup>

  Given that *any* type can be converted to a *string*, a `[string[]]` array is the trickiest case.
  You *do* get an error if (automatic) coercion cannot be performed, such as with
  `[int[]] $arr = 1, 2; $arr[0] = 'one' # error`
- **"Adding to" a specifically-typed array creates a *new* array of type `[object[]]`**:

  PowerShell conveniently allows you to "add to" arrays with the `+` operator.
  In reality, **a *new* array is created** behind the scenes with the additional element(s) appended, but that **new array is by default again of type `[object[]]`, irrespective of the type of the input array**:

  ```bash
    $intArray = [int[]] (1, 2)
    ($intArray + 4).GetType().Name # !! -> 'Object[]'
    $intArray += 3 # !! $intArray is now of type [object[]]

    # To avoid the problem...
    # ... use casting:
    ([int[]] ($intArray + 4)).GetType().Name # -> 'Int32[]'
    # ... or use a type-constrained variable:
    [int[]] $intArray = (1, 2) # a type-constrained variable
    $intArray += 3 # still of type [int[]], due to type constraint.
  ```
- **Outputting to the success stream converts any collection to `[object[]]`**:

  **Any collection with *at least 2 elements* that a command or pipeline outputs** (to the success stream) is **automatically converted to an array of type `[object[]]`**, which may be unexpected:

  ```bash
    # A specifically-typed array:
    # Note that whether or not `return` is used makes no difference.
    function foo { return [int[]] (1, 2) }
    # Important: foo inside (...) is a *command*, not an *expression*
    # and therefore a *pipeline* (of length 1)
    (foo).GetType().Name # !! -> 'Object[]'

    # A different collection type:
    function foo { return [System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2) }
    (foo).GetType().Name # !! -> 'Object[]'

    # Ditto with a multi-segment pipeline:
    ([System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2) | Write-Output).GetType().Name # !! -> 'Object[]'
  ```

  The reason for this behavior is that **PowerShell is fundamentally *collection-based***: **any command's output is sent *item by item* through the pipeline**; note that even a *single* command is a pipeline (of length 1).

  **That is, PowerShell *always* first *enumerates* (unwraps) collections, and then, if needed, *reassembles* them** - for **assignment to a *variable***, or as the **intermediate result of a *command nested inside `(...)`*** - and the **reassembled collection is *always of type `[object[]]`***.

  PowerShell considers an object a collection if its type implements the [`IEnumerable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), *except* if it also implements the [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.
  This exception means that PowerShell's hashtables ([`[hashtable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx)) and ordered hashtables (the PSv3+ literal variant with ordered keys, `[ordered] @{...}`, which is of type [`[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx)) are sent through the pipeline *as a whole*, and to instead enumerate their entries (key-value pairs) individually, you must call their `.GetEnumerator()` method.
- PowerShell by design **always *unwraps* a *single*-element output collection to that single element**:

  In other words: when a single-element collection is output, PowerShell doesn't return an *array*, but the array's single element *itself*.

  ```bash
    # The examples use single-element array ,1 
    # constructed with the unary form of array-construction operator ","
    # (Alternatively, @( 1 ) could be used in this case.)

    # Function call:
    function foo { ,1 }
    (foo).GetType().Name # -> 'Int32'; single-element array was *unwrapped*

    # Pipeline:
    ( ,1 | Write-Output ).GetType().Name # -> 'Int32'

    # To force an expression into an array, use @(...):
    @( (,1) | Write-Output ).GetType().Name # -> 'Object[]' - result is array
  ```

  Loosely speaking, the **purpose of *array* subexpression operator `@(...)`** is: Always treat the enclosed value as a *collection*, even if it contains (or would normally unwrap to) only a *single item*:
  If it is a *single* value, wrap it an `[object[]]` array with 1 element.
  Values that already are collections remain collections, though they are **converted to a *new `[object[]]` array*, even if the value itself already *is* an array**:
  `$a1 = 1, 2; $a2 = @( $a1 ); [object]::ReferenceEquals($a1, $a2)`
  outputs `$false`, proving that arrays `$a1` and `$a2` are not the same.

  Contrast this with:

  - **just `(...)`**, which **does *not per se* change the value's type** - its purpose is merely to clarify precedence or to force a new parsing context:

    - If the enclosed **construct is an *expression*** (something parsed in *expression mode*), **the type is *not* changed**; e.g., `([System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2)) -is [System.Collections.ArrayList]` and `([int[]] (1,2)) -is [int[]]` both return `$true` - the type is retained.
    - If the enclosed **construct is a *command* (single- or multi-segment *pipeline*)**, then the **default unwrapping behavior applies**; e.g.:
      `(&{ , 1 }) -is [int]` returns `$true` (the single-element array was unwrapped) and `(& { [int[]] (1, 2) }) -is [object[]]` (the `[int[]]` array was reassembled into an `[object[]]` array) both return `$true`, because the use of call operator `&` made the enclosed construct a *command*.
  - (regular) **subexpression operator `$(...)`**, typically used in expandable strings, which **exhibits the default unwrapping behavior**:
    `$(,1) -is [int]` and `$([System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2)) -is [object[]]` both return `$true`.
- **Returning a collection *as a whole*** from a function or script:

  On occasion you may want to output a collection *as a whole*, i.e., to output it as a *single* item, retaining its original type.

  As we've seen above, outputting a collection as-is causes PowerShell to unwrap it and ultimately reassemble it into a regular `[object[]]` array.

  To prevent that, the ***unary* form of array construction operator `,`** can be used to **wrap the collection in an *outer* array**, which PowerShell then unwraps to the original collection:

  ```bash
    # Wrap array list in regular array with leading ","
    function foo { , [System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2) }
    # The call to foo unwraps the outer array and assigns the original
    # array list to $arrayList.
    $arrayList = foo
    # Test
    $arrayList.GetType().Name # -> 'ArrayList'
  ```

  In **PSv4+**, use **`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`**:

  ```bash
    function foo { write-output -NoEnumerate ([System.Collections.ArrayList] (1, 2)) }
    $arrayList = foo
    $arrayList.GetType().Name # -> 'ArrayList'
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Note that **using `@(...)` to create array *literals* isn't *necessary*, because the array-construction operator `,` *alone* creates arrays**.

On versions prior to PSv5.1, you also pay a (in most cases probably negligible) performance penalty, because the `,`-constructed array inside `@()` is effectively *cloned* by `@()` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091504/45375) of mine for details.

**That said, `@(...)` has advantages**:</sup>

- You can use the same syntax, whether your array literal contains a single (`@( 1 )` or multiple elements (`@( 1, 2 )`). Contrast this with just using `,`: `1, 2` vs. `, 1`.
- You needn't `,`-separate the lines of a *multiline* `@(...)` statements (though note that each line then technically becomes its own statement).
- There are no operator-precedence pitfalls, because `$(...)` and `@(...)` have the highest precedence.

<sup>[2] PetSerAl provides this advanced code snippet to show the **limited scenarios in which PowerShell *does* respect casts**, namely in the context of **overload resolution for .NET method calls**:</sup>

```bash
# Define a simple type that implements an interface
# and a method that has 2 overloads.
Add-Type '
  public interface I { string M(); }
  public class C : I {
           string I.M()       { return "I.M()"; } // interface implementation
    public string M(int i)    { return "C.M(int)"; } 
    public string M(object o) { return "C.M(object)"; } 
  }
'
# Instantiate the type and use casts to distinguish between
# the type and its interface, and to target a specific overload.
$C = New-Object C
$C.M(1)           # default: argument type selects overload -> 'C.M(int)' 
([I]$C).M()       # interface cast is respected -> 'I.M()'
$C.M([object]1)   # argument cast is respected -> 'C.M(object)'
```