# how do you select just one property from an array of "results" from the Azure command 'az group list in powershell'?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to select just one property from an array of "result" (objects?) which come back from the Azure command `az group list` in powershell?

I know this sounds trivial, but here's where it gets strange, and I hope there is a simple explanation.

If I run the Azure command `az group list -o table` (after I have succesfully logged in using `az login`) I get the following typical response

```bsh
PS src> az group list -o table             
Name              Location    Status
----------------  ----------  ---------
group0            westeurope  Succeeded
group1            westeurope  Succeeded
group2            uksouth     Succeeded
group3            westeurope  Succeeded
group4            westeurope  Succeeded
group5            westeurope  Succeeded
group6            westeurope  Succeeded
group7            uksouth     Succeeded
group8            westeurope  Succeeded
group9            westeurope  Succeeded
```

however, if I try to select just the `Name` property by doing

> az group list | select -p name

Then i get about 2 screens full of empty lines, with nothing displayed. So the question is, what's wrong with the command above? And how should I fix it?

I tried the following experiments to dig into the exact types of objects being returned and get some results that I don't understand. I'm hoping this will make sense to someone with more Azure and powershell experience.

Here's the steps to reproduce the problem very easily, assuming you have an azure account.

1. start powershell, e.g. on mac terminal, type `pwsh`
2. log in to azure `az login`
3. type `az group list -o table`

observe that the list comes back and is formatted correctly.

4. type `az group list | select -p name`

observe a few screens full of blank lines. no text.

5. scratch your head and wonder whats just happened? (grin)

**THE PLOT THICKENS**

`az group list` on it's own returns a few screens full of this

```
[
 ... lots of these ...
 {
    "id": "/subscriptions/this-is-super-wierd-i-cant-select-name-prop/resourceGroups/spikes",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "spikes",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": {},
    "type": null
  }
]
```

however, `(az group list).getType()` returns

```bsh
PS src> (az group list).getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

and lastly, hopefully the last 2 pieces of the puzzle

```bsh
PS src> (az group list)[0].getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

so the return types from `az group list` appear to be an `array of objects` or maybe it's an array of `object[]`, my powershell is scratchy here. So to double check, I query for the first 10 elements of that array by doing...`(az group list)[0..10]` and that returns bizarely `10 strings!`. Ok, I know it's supposed to be 10 strings, only because it's a computer and if that's what it is, then, that's what it really is. I just dont understand why.

```bsh
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/resourceGroups/somegroup",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "admin",
    "properties": {
      "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "tags": {},
    "type": null
```

So all of this, to cut a long story short, is I'm wanting to know, how do you select just one property from the result of an azure query? In my case, I simply want to display the names of all my resource groups.

This `az group list | select -p name` should work, but does not, and I'd like to know how to do it properly, and in the process find out why it didn't work, and we can all learn something about Azure and powershell in the process, and life can be great!

Love you all,
Alan

Comment: Last thing I observed while testing both proposed solutions, is that you need to surround the convertfrom-json method in brackets, or you get no results back. 

So, this works `( az group list | convertfrom-json ) | select id, location`. 
and this does not `az group list | convertfrom-json  | select id, location` (returns zero records). Finally, just to point out that if you're not using powershell, e.g. you're running the query in bash as part of an azure build step, then use @4c74356b41 approach so u don't need 2 shell to powershell.

Comment: I used `jq` in shell for years but should have just learned how to properly use the `--query`/`--output` parameters instead. I've found this to be the best approach because your AZ CLI scripts will work in what ever shell you try.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's work through this. When we specify `-o table` e.g.:

```
az group list -o table
```

We say to Azure PowerShell CLI take the JSON content you get, and format it into a nice table for us. Typically, we don't want to work with RAW JSON, and we don't want to work with formatted tables either. Working with string arrays in PowerShell are also not a nice thing to use. In PowerShell, we want to work with "nice" easy objects. So, let's look at the other ways to get our information. Let's take your example and simply save it to a variable that we can look at:

```
$GroupList = az group list
```

Then if we look as the type:

```
PS C:\> $GroupList.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Indeed, we have an array of objects. They *must* be an array of our groups... right?... well no. It's not what you think. If we look at the size of the array and return the first few elements of the array we will see what's going on:

```
PS C:\> $GroupList.Count
125
PS C:\Temp> $GroupList[0..2]
[
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/resourceGroups/somegroup",
```

Well, that's not what we wanted. The array is far to large... and looking at the content reveals that what we actually have is an array of each line of the JSON **text**. This means that running:

```
az group list | select -p name
```

or:

```
$GroupList | select -p name
```

Is saying, loop through the array, and only output the "Name" property. Since the "Name" property does not exist on a string of text, it simply outputs a blank line. Since there are a few hundred lines of text, we get a few hundred lines of blanks.

So why does PowerShell take the input and break it into an array of strings separated by new lines? Isn't this kinda hard to use? Isn't this not a "great" way to handle a JSON formatted text? Why don't we just get one giant string? Isn't that easier to handle and parse? What's the one reason for this oddness?

Well with PowerShell, the need to support pipelines drives decisions on how we output objects:

> "The primary purpose ... is to provide a way to ensure that the result of a pipeline execution is always an indexable collection."
>   [Quote](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4280#issuecomment-316220967)

This is why we get an array of objects outputted (See: [@mklement0 answer here for more in depth discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373523/2150063)) to support pipeline operations. And if we look at how text files are read and written to, we can highlight exactly why we end up with this specific <s>*cough* Programmer *cough* convenience *cough*</s>... I mean weirdness.

To set things up, we can pipe the output directly to a text file:

```
az group list | Out-File -FilePath List.json
```

Woah, wait a second, why did that just work? (In situations like this, I like to say that PowerShell does **Magic!**), Don't we have to mess with looping through arrays, appending strings terminated with newlines to get one giant contiguous block of text that ends with an EOF, and exactly matches our desired text file?

A simplified reason behind what really happens? Well, <s>out of programmer convenience,</s> `Out-File` takes the array of strings, iterates through it, and does a simple `File.WriteLine()` for each string (not bad for a 3 line for loop!). Hence, we just generated a nice JSON formatted text file complete with newlines without breaking a sweat. Reading it back in:

```
PS C:\> $ListFromFile = Get-Content .\List.json
PS C:\> $ListFromFile.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\> $ListFromFile.Count
125
```

Does the reverse. It takes the file, does a `File.ReadLine()`, appends the strings to an array, and returns it. That's why we end up with an object array that contains strings.

Now, what do we ***really*** want? Well we know from the start, we don't want to work with one giant string, and we ***especially*** don't want to work with strings in an object array, what we want to work with is a nice native `PSCustomObject` that we can access. That's what PowerShell works best with, that's what we work best with. So, we simply have to convert our (big air quotes) "text input", which we know is formatted as JSON, and convert it into an object:

```
$List = $GroupList | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And looking at the count and properties:

```
PS C:\> $List.Count
10
PS C:\> $List.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\> $List[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

We see the count now matches how many groups we have, and the types are no longer an array of strings, but actual objects. So... ***Now***, we can start sorting and selecting:

```
PS C:\> $List | select -Property Name

Name            
----
group0
group1
group2
group3
group4
group5
group6
group7
group8
group9
```

And we get the output that we *really* wanted.

Comment: Superb! Is there any way to say more thanks than simply "upvote" and mark as 'answer'? :D grin!

Comment: summarising what you've just said, we arrive at `(az group list | convertfrom-json).Name`

Comment: what confuses matters is that the response is not json. It's an array of strings that reprents the json lines in a json file, one string per line, not one string per item in the collection that the json represents.

Comment: I think this line in your description is not 100% accurate, ` So, we simply have to convert our text, which we know is formatted as JSON, into an object:`, perhaps should read, " So, we simply have to convert our text, which we know is formatted as a pretty printed JSON text string split into string parts with one string per newline of text portion of the json , into an object:" <- But I know we can kinda think of it as json.

Comment: You're right the original description is not *100%* accurate, I forgot to add... (big air quotes) "text input"... ;-)... but, as an aside, you did raise a good point about it. I generically referred it as "text" and nothing too specific because that's how **I** treat it, and **I** treat it like a block of text (even if it is all chopped up into an unusable messy object array). I added more information to the answer to delve into why the data gets into that "weird" format.

Comment: +100 for the great description explaining the messy strings with Powershell. Powershell is this really strange beast that pretends to be 'explorable' yet is so full of the most absurd edge cases that defy all reasoning. If you try to just explore and reason about it, 9 times out of 10, you will be rewarded with knowledge, and the tenth time ... powershell will lock you up in a dungeon. PS makes up for this though with the friendliest dev community on the planet ! (hearts)

Answer (score 16):

wow, so much text for something as simple as:

```
az group list --query '[].name' -o tsv
```

In the query, we use `[]` because the output of a `list` command is an array. Next, we select the single column that we want, `name`. If we wanted to select more than one column, we would use `[name, BaseType]`. All "list" commands in the Azure CLI return an array, but if use any other CLI command which returns a single result, we would simply use `--query 'name'`.

By default, the output of a Azure CLI Command is json. We use `--output` or `-o` to change the format, and we select `tsv` because it provides the cleanest output.

Comment: hahaha! I know right :D To be fair, my question specifically asks to know why, i.e. to learn something from this and understand what exactly what coming back with all the different types. @HAL9256 explained it perfectly step by step. It's super interesting and this particular problem crops up quite often, so it's worth getting our heads around it.

Comment: If you explain why the --query with the '[].name' magically works, in such a way that knowing why will help with other uses of powershell I'll upvote your answer. (and so will others if they like it.)

Comment: `(az group list | convertfrom-json).name` is the short cut version of "all the text" :D

Comment: So the `--query` is JMESPath (jason query path syntax) http://jmespath.org/ , and the fact that the array of object[] (strings) can be queried with a `JMESPath` is as a result of the implementation of `az group list` no other reason? Is there anything we can learn from this, that we can use with other commands? The output `-o` is specified as `tab separated values`, will that cause difficulties if piped into another command?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about, you are getting an array of strings, nothing unexpected is happening. if you process them as json you would get objects you can act upon. but this is over engineering. you can just get a list of names using Az Cli syntax

Comment: Now I'm confused. When you say "this is over engineering", what are you referring to? The whole discussion, or the proposed solution? by proposed solution I mean `(az group list | convertfrom-json).name`. What specifically has been over-engineered?

Comment: ...also, we don't get an array of strings. We can phystically "see" an array of strings, and it acts like an array of strings, but the real type that is returned is `System.Array` of `object[]`. or in C# `object[][]` ? (I might be wrong, see the code at the top) Now that *can* be used to hold strings, but is really very different to `string[]`. I do appreciate that once you grok what it is, it all becomes simple, and that's the journey that @HAL9256 was taking us on, explaining the oddities, which was the essence of the OP's (my) question.

Comment: you dont need powershell to get list of names from az cli, you can use native az cli capabilities. using 1 tool is always better than using 2 tools.

Comment: why do you think that? its just an array of strings, nothing more

Comment: @snowcode I know this is an ancient thread, but it's one of the first things people are finding when they search the question. Added a little bit of context to the answer. the particular issue with `(az group list | convertfrom-json).name` is it is environment specific, while using the `--query` and `--output` parameters will work, regardless if you have installed az cli in shell, bash, or pwsh.