# Defining a strictly-typed variable that is an Array of a particular data type

Tags: powershell

You can define a strictly-typed variable that is an Array with the following declaration:
`[System.Array]$VariableNameArray`

You can also define a strictly-typed variable that is an Integer with the following declaration:
`[System.Int]$VariableNameInteger`

However, is there a way to define a strictly-typed variable that is an Array of Integers (and not, for example, a scalar integer, or an array of strings)?

Comment: `[int[]] $myArray`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array Types In Powershell - System.Object\[\] vs. arrays with specific types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355649/array-types-in-powershell-system-object-vs-arrays-with-specific-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type literal syntax for an array of a given type is `TypeName[]`, so to type a variable to be an array of `int`'s:

```
[int[]]$integerArrayVariableName = ...
```